# KineticJS - Difference between setPoints and SetPosition

Tags: position, line, kineticjs

I am trying to set the position of a line using

```
 Line1.setPosition([0, 512 + newX, 1024, 512 + newX]);
```

It does not work right, the line moves to a wrong position.  However when I use:

```
 Line1.setPoints([0, 512 + newX, 1024, 512 + newX]);
```

I works, but I need to use setPosition for the rest of my script to work.  I would appreciate your suggestions, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setPoints sets the array of points for drawing a line, or other object which needs points to be drawn.

setPosition sets only the (X,Y) value of the related position of the object. It only accepts two numbers as parameters.

When you create your line start it with x,y at 0,0, then set the position using an x,y amount.

This example explains the difference:

```
Line1 = new Kinetic.Line({
    x:0,                  //  can be modified by .setPosition(x,y) or .setX()
    y:0,                  //  can be modified by .setPosition(x,y) or .setY() 
    points: [0, 512, 1024, 512]  // can be modified by .setPoints(array)
});
```

Comment: no problem, but I would not use setPosition, if you need to move things around use .move(x,y), as it is a faster function.

Comment: do be aware that .move() does not set a coordinate position, but rather moves your object by an amount

Comment: so .setPosition(10, 10) sets the object at 10,10     while     .move(10,10) moves an object 10 to the right, and 10 down.